# Retrieve email belonging to username in android

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-services, soap

I have to develop a login form android application.Here, i have to enter the username and password. If it is correct, fetch the email belonging to the username and display it in the textview and if the username and password is wrong, display login failed message.

This is my webservice code:

```
public class Login { 
    public String authentication(String username,String password) {
        String retrievedUserName = "";
        String retrievedPassword = "";
        String retrievedEmail = "";
        String status = "";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xcart-432pro","root","");
            PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM xcart_customers WHERE login = '"+username+"'");
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            while(result.next()){  
                retrievedUserName = result.getString("login");
                retrievedPassword = result.getString("password");
                retrievedEmail = result.getString("email");  
            }
            if(retrievedUserName.equals(username)&&retrievedPassword.equals(password)&&!(retrievedUserName.equals("") && retrievedPassword.equals(""))){
                status = "Success";
            }
            else {
                status = "Login fail!!!";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
};
```

This is my android code:

```
public class CustomerLogin extends Activity {
    private static final String SPF_NAME = "vidslogin";
    private static final String USERNAME = "login";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = null;

    CheckBox chkRememberMe;
    private String login;
    String mGrandTotal,total,mTitle;

    EditText username,userPassword;
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
    private final String URL = "http://10.0.0.75:8085/XcartLogin/services/Login?wsdl";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/authentication";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "authentication";
    private String uName;

    /**Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.customer_login);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        total = b.getString("GrandTotal");
        mTitle = b.getString("Title");
        TextView grandtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grand_total);
        grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + mTitle );
        chkRememberMe = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.rempasswordcheckbox);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
        userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
        SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SPF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        username.setText(loginPreferences.getString(USERNAME, ""));
        userPassword.setText(loginPreferences.getString(PASSWORD, ""));
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                loginAction();
            }
        });
    }

    private void loginAction(){
        boolean isUserValidated = true;
        boolean isPasswordValidated = true;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
        String user_Name = username.getText().toString();
        EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
        String user_Password = userPassword.getText().toString();

        //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
        PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
        unameProp.setName("username");//Define the variable name in the web service method
        unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
        unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
        request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable

        //Pass value for Password variable of the web service
        PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
        passwordProp.setName("password");
        passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
        passwordProp.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(passwordProp);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try{
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String status = response.toString();
            TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
            result.setText(response.toString());

            if(status.equals("Success")) {
                //   ADD  to save  and  read next time
                String strUserName = username.getText().toString().trim();
                String strPassword = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if (null == strUserName || strUserName.length() == 0) {
                    //  showToast("Enter Your Name");
                    username.setError( "username is required!" );
                    isUserValidated = false;
                }
                if (null == strPassword || strPassword.length() == 0) {
                    //      showToast("Enter Your Password");
                    isPasswordValidated = false;
                    userPassword.setError( "password is required!" );
                } 
                if (isUserValidated = true && isPasswordValidated == true) {
                    if (chkRememberMe.isChecked()) {
                        SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SPF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        loginPreferences.edit().putString(USERNAME, strUserName).putString(PASSWORD, strPassword).commit();
                    } 
                    else {
                        SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SPF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        loginPreferences.edit().clear().commit();
                    }
                }
                if (isUserValidated && isPasswordValidated) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerLogin.this,PayPalIntegrationActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("GrandTotal", total);
                    intent.putExtra("Title", mTitle);
                    intent.putExtra("login",username.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
            else {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_custom_layout,
                        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 30);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setView(layout);
                toast.show();

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

If the login is success, it will have to display the email on textview. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use asy task to do this,

**in doInBackground**

Do your login operations. Asyctask makes this  operation in another task.

**when complated  in onPostExecute**

show the success message. **But you need to use runOnUiThread because you cant reach ui controls from non ui thread**.

```
private class loginTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, int> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

         // start login process

         return 1;
     }


     protected void onPostExecute(int result) {

           _activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textview.setText("login success");
                }
            });

     }
 }
```